# Target WSGI script cannot be loaded as Python module Flask

Tags: python, web-services, flask, apache2, raspberry-pi2

So, i've been working on this little project in apache2 using python and Flask microframework. I have this problem.

```
mod_wsgi (pid=11251): Target WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskr/wsgi.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskr/wsgi.wsgi'``
File "/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskr/wsgi.wsgi", line 8, in <module>
from flaskr import app  as application
ImportError: cannot import name 'app'
```

This is what my wsgi.wsgi file looks like.

```
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,'/var/wwww/FlaskApp')

from flaskr import app  as application
```

and this what my .conf files looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *>
            ServerName (here goes my ip)
            ServerAdmin "me"
            WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi
            WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskr/wsgi.wsgi
            <Directory /var/www/FlaskAppr/flaskr>
                    WSGIProcessGroup wsgi
                    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

                    Require all granted
            </Directory>
            Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskr/static
            <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            LogLevel warn
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

so, far been roaming internet, got no answers. Flask local works ok. 
Yet, i still get the 500 error whenever i try to run apache2

Btw, i am using a ***raspberry pi as server. Stretch version OS.***

any ideas?

Comment: The error message is complaining about the last line of your wsgi.wsgi file. I suggest you check the documentation of flaskr.

Comment: Yeah. Fixed already thanks! Had to do. flaskr.app